# Typesafe config missing key in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, configuration-files, typesafe-config

I want to run a spark app where I put my configurations in a configuration file using the typesafe config library. However, everytime I try to run the code using that library, I get an error saying typesafe config cannot find a key (so MissingKey errors).

My project's folder looks like this:

```
-project
    -assembly.sbt
    -build.properties
-src
    -main
        -resources
            -myApp.conf
        -scala
            -com/myApp/App.scala
    -test
-build.sbt
```

I want to use typesafe config for configuration data and I store those configs in myApp.conf. File looks like this:

```
cassandra {
host = "localhost"
keyspace = "kspace"
table = "data"
}

spark {
master = "localhost"
appName = "myApp"
}
```

The `myApp.scala` file loads the configs and then uses them to setup sessions and context:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("myApp")

  val hosts = config.getString("cassandra.host")
  val keyspace = config.getString("cassandra.keyspace")
  val table = config.getString("cassandra.table")

  val appName = config.getString("spark.appName")
  val master = config.getString("spark.master")

  val sparkconf = new SparkConf(true)
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)

  val sc = new SparkContext(master, appName, sparkconf)
```

The following is the content of sbt:

```
name := "myApp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.5",
  "com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" % "2.0.2",
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.6.0-M5" exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core","jackson-databind"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
)
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work if you change the config name to `application.conf` and use the empty overload of `ConfigFactory.load`?

Comment: No it does not. I have tested that too.

Comment: It seems your configuration is not accessible from spark executors. Spark requires objects to be serializable in order to be passed over to the executors. I would rather use a @transient lazy val object and pass in the the configuration name using executor java options so that spark serializer ignores and yet the configuration is available to the executors.